# What determines who can view an unpublished node?

Tags: 7, users

The [Node Access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/group/node_access/7) documentation explains that there are three things that affect node permissions, used in this order of preference until an answer is received: an overriding `bypass node access` permission; `hook_node_access` (used on single nodes and not in listings); `hook_node_grants` (which compares against the `node_access` table).

What I can't see is how (un)published content is handled. The only default implementation of `hook_node_access` is [`node_node_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_node_access/7) which you can see completely ignores the 'view' mode, answering only for create/delete/edit modes.

The [`hook_node_grants`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7) docs say explicitly that (un)published content is "not handled by the system".

But there are the checkboxes in the user permissions table for `view published content` and `view own unpublished content` etc. Where are these implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is handled by [`node_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7):

- it checks for the "view published content" - without this permission every operation is denied, published or not.
- it checks the `view own unpublished content` permission.
- it checks if `hook_node_access` gives either deny/allow. If not...
- If **no** module implements `hook_node_grants` then there's a default allow for published nodes (and therefore a deny if not).
- If modules **do** implement `hook_node_grants` then the `node_access` table is consulted. I found that published content receives a "default grant" in the node_access table thanks to [node_access_acquire_grants](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access_acquire_grants/7), meaning anyone can view it. Unpublished content has no default grant so is therefore denied.

Answer (score 0):

basically the unpublished content is visible only to those roles that have "Administer content" permission.

you can use [this module](http://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished) but I had some problems with it and decided to build my own, lighter module.

Comment: Where is that checked? Do you mean that the `view own unpublished content` is not used anywhere?

Comment: It's not true: Unpublished nodes are also visible to their authors, when they have the "view own unpublished content" permission.

Comment: yep, @kiamlaluno you're right, sorry, my question was rhetorical. Pls. see my full answer above.

Comment: @artfulrobot I was saying that to Marius Illie. His answer is not correct for Drupal 7.

Comment: This is not correct. The permission you meant to say is "Bypass content access control". Then there's a second permission "View own unpublished content" as well.